# c# How to find the sibling of the same polymorphic chain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I'm not quite sure how to describe this question but will give it a go and edit in the process.

I have a polymorphic code structure:

1. public interface IFoodItem
2. public interface IFruitItemModel : IFoodItem

3a. public class PooledFruitItem : IFruitItemModel

3b. public interface IJuiceModel : IFruitItemModel

3c. public interface IPieModel : IFruitItemModel

4a. public class JuiceModel : IJuiceModel

4b. public class PieModel : IPieModel

Hope this structure is clear to you.

The code sends me a message each time an item, a juice or a pie is being clicked on.

In return I need to "show" in the game, the clicked item.

The item from the message is IFruitItemModel of type PooledFruitItem.
I need to take this item and connect it to one of the "JuiceModel" or "PieModel"

this is the code:

```
    private void ShowFruitItem(IFruitItemModel fruitModel) {
        if (fruitModel is IPieModel) {
            table.SetPie((fruitModel as IPieModel).PieObject);
        } else {
            table.SetJuice((fruitModel as IJuiceModel).JuiceTexture);
        }
    }
```

The issue I have with this method is that fruitModel of type PooledFruitItem, doesn't find the connection to JuiceModel, even though they have the same parent.

Is it possible for 3a. PooledFruitItem, to find its way to 4a. IJuiceModel?

Thank you

Comment: I'd put the `ShowFuritItem` method into `IFruitItemModel` so that it can be implemented in `PooledFruiteItem`, `PieModel` and `JucieModel` accordingly.  Then you'd call `fruitModel.ShowFruitItem(table);`

Comment: Hi @juharr, a solution that worked for me was to create a variable of type IFruitItemModel, and in JuiceModel and PieModel, in the getter set to: return this. This way the method in PooledFruitItem could reach the correct IFruitItemModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the hierarchy to get to IJuiceModel...

```
IFoodItem <- IFruitItemModel <- IJuiceModel
```

However, here's the hierarchy for PooledFruitItem...

```
IFoodItem <- IFruitItemModel <- PooledFruitItem
```

The reason it's not classified as juice is because PooledFruitItem doesn't implement IJuiceModel!

To do that, you'd need:

```
IFoodItem <- IFruitItemModel <- IJuiceModel <- PooledFruitItem
```

...or in class form:

```
//*** NOT this ***
public class PooledFruitItem : IFruitItemModel {}

//*** THIS ***
public class PooledFruitItem : IJuiceModel {}
```

Also note, your cast is going to fail and return null in some cases:

```
else {
        //*** All we know here is is that we don't have an IPieModel, 
        //*** but that doens't necessarily mean we have an IJuiceModel
        //*** That means "fruitModel as IJuiceModel" may return null.
        table.SetJuice((fruitModel as IJuiceModel).JuiceTexture);
    }
```

This makes more sense given your stated structure:

```
private void ShowFruitItem(IFruitItemModel fruitModel) 
{
    if (fruitModel is IPieModel) 
        DoPie(fruitModel as IPieModel);
    else if (fruitModel is IJuiceModel)
        DoJuice(fruitModel as IJuiceModel);
    else
        DoFruit(fruitModel);
}
```